# How can JavaScript check if element is a specific color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of code that needs to check if an element matches a color, and if it does, change it. Otherwise it is set to a default color.

```js
var caps = $("#caps");
if (caps.css('background-color') == "rgb(225, 0, 0)") {
  $('body').on('click', '#caps', function(event) {
    $('.clight').css({
      'background-color': 'red',
      'box-shadow': '0px 0px 20px yellow'
    });
    $('#l2').css({
      'background-color': 'red',
      'box-shadow': '0px 0px 20px yellow'
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $('.clight').css('background-color', 'white');
  });
```

```css
.caps {
  /* Caps button CSS */
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.clight {
  /* Caps button light CSS */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="key caps" id="caps">
  <!-- Caps Lock Key -->
  <div class="clight">
    <!-- Caps Lock  Light-->
  </div> Caps<br>Lock
</div>
```

It doesn't work however. All I am trying to do is to switch on the caps lock light when you click, and switch it back of if you click it again, almost like a toggle.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle or put full html code here with CSS?

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: better go with a class here

Comment: there is a little small trick you have to do before checking in every case. you have to set a background-color on the selected node before you can get a response from $(selector).css('background-color'). It does not work if this is not set before requesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be very simple:

```
$('body').on('click', '#caps', function(event){
      $('.clight, #l2').toggleClass('on');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Just noticed that you have some javascript error in your code as the closing of your `click` event is getting closed at wrong place.*

---

Well there is no concrete method to do such things as different browser have different settings for color codes some uses `rgb()` some `hex` etc.

I would rather suggest you to create some classes and look for them instead like:

```
.bg-red{ background-color:red; }

$('body').on('click', '#caps', function(event){
  if ($(this).hasClass('bg-red')) {
      $('.clight, #l2').css({
         'background-color' : 'red',
         'box-shadow' :  '0px 0px 20px yellow'
      });
      event.preventDefault();
  } else {
      $('.clight').css('background-color' , 'white');  
  }
});
```